# MySQL база с 10 гб и SELECT с %LIKE%

Tags: mysql

Есть база данных, вес ~10 гб, количество строк 45 млн (они разбиты по таблицам).

Есть 10 столбцов, нужно делать поиск по 1 столбцу тип которого varchar.

fulltext index в MySQL не совсем подходит, так как поиск идет после *, например: apple*, а нужно искать именно слова в которых вхождение *ppl*, это на примере слова apple.

Sphinx тоже как я прочитал ищет таким образом, поэтому тоже не подходит.

Подскажите, что в данном случае лучше использовать?

Спасибо

Comment: Мало информации. В каком контексте поиск? Это может быть поиск на сайте по запросу пользователя. А может быть работа аналитика без существенных ограничений по времени.

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/03/19/speed-pattern-matching-queries/

Comment: Это не поиск по сайту, поиск выполнять буду только я. @Mike, LIKE не подходит так как очень долго выполняется.

Comment: по той ссылке что я скинул вообще то сравнивается like с триграмным индексом на основе отдельной таблицы.  что может быть либо быстрее либо медленнее like в зависимости от специфики ваших данных. Надо попробовать подход с триграммами или возможно с другими длинами ключа. Я это предложил попробовать потому что специализированный триграмный индекс в postgresql дает отличные результаты в работе like '%xxx%', но там это именно специальный вид индекса а в mysql придется как в статье по ссылке делать отдельную таблицу.

Comment: @Mike, абсолютно все значения уникальны, делать еще одну таблицу не совсем понимаю зачем. Вы про команду explain в запросе MySQL?

Comment: В отдельной таблице хранятся все трехбуквенные (или другие) сочетания, выделяемые из текста, а не исходные данные. Поэтому поиск фактически идет на равенство. Прочитайте статью внимательнее.

Comment: @Mike, хорошо, я тогда объясню на примере, допустим есть слово apple, сейчас я ищу ppl, потом буду искать app, допустим слово application, я буду искать сейчас licat, потом cati, таким образом, как я понял, та задумка не поможет в моем случае.

Comment: application разбивается на app, ppl, pli, lic, ica и т.д. так что ppl находится прямым равенством. Для поиска licat надо найти такие id для которых есть триграммы lic, ica, cat т.е. выбор из трех равенств и потом перепроверить результаты.

Comment: @Mike, иногда поиск происходит по 3 символам, иногда по 4, иногда по 5. Такой метод не совсем подходит.

Comment: Любой поиск по тексту с произвольного места может работать только по такому принципу. Под капотом всех БД, которые это умеют используется этот же подход, в той или иной модификации. Так что либо делать этот самому, либо перейти на postgresql, где это уже реализовано (в расширении pg_tgrm)